# Waiting for array from another class to be loaded

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been searching for a while trying to figure this out, I am most likely missing an obvious answer.

I have arrays of various types that get loaded in an injectable class when the app starts, data is loaded from backend api

Loading of the data is fine, I call the api and subscribe for the response, load it and away we go

But I have some components later on that depend on those lists having data as I may need to filter them in their OnInit's, how can I check/wait for those lists to be loaded?

ItemList class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ItemList  {
  ....
  ....
  public  oneList: Map<string, string>;
  public  twoList: Object[];
  ....
}
```

InitLoader class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { ItemList } from '../_common/constant/item-list';

@Injectable()

export class InitLoader {
       constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient,
                   private itemList:ItemList) {}

       public load() {
            ....
            ....                
            this.httpClient.get(url)
               .subscribe( res =>{
               ...
               ...
               this.itemList.oneList = res['oneListData'];
               this.itemList.twoList = res['twoListData'];
               ...
               ...
           }

       }
   }
```

In my app.component.ts I call the load() method

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

      ...
      ...        
      constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
                  private router: Router ,
                  private initLoader:InitLoader,
                  private items:ItemList )  {  

                 this.initLoader.load();
       ....
       }
```

Then finally in a page component where I would like to use one of the lists, I need to do some work/filtering of a list in the ngOnInit(), which if the data hasn't loaded yet I will have issues

```
import { ItemList } from '../_common/constant/item-list';

@Component({ 
      selector: 'page-one',
      templateUrl: './page-one.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./page-one.component.less']
})
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( public router: Router,
        public items:ItemList) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {

        this.items.oneList.filter(x => x.value == "blah");
}
```

So in my PageOneComponent how can I check and wait for this list to be loaded so that I can then filter? This is in a modest sized project that is pretty far along with many other components that rely on these lists, so hoping to avoid some major restructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `BehaviourSubject` of the fields that you require in `PageOneComponent`  in your InitLoader Service. When you get the response in your `InitLoader` load method, push that data into the `BehaviourSubject`. Also, create a getter for that `BehaviourSubject` for easy access.

Then in your `PageOneComponent`, use the getter of that `BehaviourSubject` to get the value only when it is loaded, or wait for it while being it is loaded using the subscribe method.

InitLoader Service

```js
   itemList$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

      this.httpClient.get(url)
               .subscribe( res =>{
               ...
               ...
               this.itemList.oneList = res['oneListData'];
               this.itemList.twoList = res['twoListData'];
               this.itemList$.next(this.itemList);
               ...
               ...
           }

    getItemList(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return this.itemList$; 
    }
```

`PageOneComponent`

```js
import { ItemList } from '../_common/constant/item-list';

@Component({ 
      selector: 'page-one',
      templateUrl: './page-one.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./page-one.component.less']
})
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( 
        public router: Router,
        public items: ItemList,
        private initLoader: InitLoader) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
       this.initLoader.getItemList().subscribe(
          resp => { 
             if(!resp) { 
                console.log(resp);
                //Do your filtering etc here
             } 
          }
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with BehaviorSubjects yet so I have some reading to do. I do notice that the subscribe does get fired on page load even if there is no data, resp is showing as undefined, so I guess the if statement is always necessary, it does get fired a 2nd time once data is loaded which is good... I think I'll just drop a 'true' into itemLIst$ so that I'm not sending all the data out again, lists can be quite large

Comment: @MikeM , I think if  You use the `ReplaySubject` as it does not need an initial value, you can remove that `if` statement which we are using to check for data.